# php - search for string in string and replace that

Tags: php, regex

i am asking the question which can be answered by a small attempt in googling but i am not finding anything which can do this, so i am asking here. pls dont downvote and close it, it can be useful for others also:

my problem is: i need to look for some portion of string, and find that and replace that. but my problem is that that portion of string is changing everytime, so i need to inject some regexp.

```
$url = "www.google.com/test=2";
replace the 'test=2' with 'test=1'
$result = "www.google.com/test=1"
```

the thing is: the slug can have any number between 1 - 20: `test=\d{1,20}` this is the case. i tried `preg_replace`, `substr_replace` but none of them can do this.

Comment: Show us the exact code you tried

Comment: here is what i tried http://codepad.org/ZZNNr1bH

Comment: The issue you're facing is you have missed out your delimiters in the preg_replace call

Comment: You match numbers from 0-20 with this regex: http://regex101.com/r/nI7aI1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see what's wrong with the following `/test=\d+/`? I think your problem is that you're forgetting the modifiers (in your example: http://codepad.org/ZZNNr1bH, but you have to use modifiers like so: http://codepad.org/9TEkPYJo)

```
<?php
    $url = "www.google.com/test=2";
    $result = preg_replace("/test=\d+/", "test=1", $url);
    //                      ^        ^
    var_dump($result);
?>
```

**Update**:

That said, like Ashley mentioned, `\d{1,20}` doesn't mean "one to twenty" but rather "any digit character repeated 1 to 20 times".

If you only want digits from 0-20, use the following regex:

```
/test=([0-9]|1[0-9]|20)/
```

Basically meaning (a number from 0-9 OR the number 1 FOLLOWED by any number between 0-9 OR the number 20)

It could also be shortened to

```
/test=(1?\d|20)/
```

Meaning (1 repeated 1 or 0 times followed by a digit from 0-9 OR the number 20)

Answer (score 1):

Also, \d{1,20} won't match the numbers between 1 and 20, but 0 and 99,999,999,999,999,999,999 which is not exactly what I think you're after.

Comment: what will it match then? i am not regexp guru

Comment: @doniyor It will match any digit character (0-9) repeated 1-20 times.

Comment: oh bad option :). thanks for guidance! so \d+ is the best one here?

Comment: @doniyor Check my updated response on how to only match 0-20. It's a bit more tricky than you may think. `\d+` means "any digit (`\d`) repeated 1 or more times (`+`) so it could be indefinitely big.

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = "www.google.com/test=2";
$replacement = 1;
echo preg_replace('/(.*test)=([1-20])/', "$1=1" ,$url);
```

If I understand the question correctly, this should do.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "website.com/test=1/asdasd/....";
$check= "test=1";
$newval = "test=2"

if(strstr($url,$check))
  $result = preg_replace($check, $newval, $url);
```

if the value is contained inside the string, then it can be replaced.